# Proxmox - redirect all ports to a specific vm

Tags: virtualization, reverse-proxy, virtual-machines, proxmox

I wanted to ask if it would be possible to access all ports of a virtual machine using a subdomain.

As a small example:

host: 10.0.2.1

VM1: 10.0.2.2

VM2: 10.0.2.3

As result:

vm1.example.com:any -> 10.0.2.2:any

vm2.example.com:any -> 10.0.2.3:any

I was thinking of a reverse proxy, but if I understood it correctly, there would have to be an entry for each port.

Is there an easier way to address Proxmox virtual machines with only one domain?

Comment: If you need access to the ports only from internal network, then just add A records for each VM, mapping the DNS name to IP address.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. Unfortunately i need to access to the ports from external

Comment: In that case you need to have public IP address for every VM you are running, and assign DNS names to those addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Implement IPv6. Use globally routable /64s on every subnet.

For both IPv4 and IPv6, send traffic via public addresses through reverse proxies and other load balancing methods. Several reverse proxies are capable of opening a port range. Implement a firewall and open the necessary ports.

For IPv4, use NAT (NAPT) where you must due to address shortages. From the outside, you can't tell hosts behind a NAT apart just by name or IP.  Either implement IPv6, connect to a jump box or reverse proxy, or use different ports and map those in your NAT. Note that NAT port mapping will not work if you need *all* ports to go to multiple hosts.